# Tortle Monk's Natural Armor and Unarmored Defense

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, racial-traits, armor-class

Depending on your skills, at some point the Monk's Unarmored Defense (10 + DEX + WIS) can and will exceed the Tortle's Natural Armor of 17.  When this happens, do you get the choice of taking the highest of the two, or are you stuck with one or the other?

IE, will Unarmored Defense always overwrite Natural Armor, or will Natural Armor always overwrite Unarmored Defense, or can you choose between the two?

Comment: Where is the Tortle from? I'm not familiar with that race.

Comment: @Erik it was just released in conjunction with Tomb of Annihilation release as a separate product available on DM's Guild and DND Beyond.  all of it's proceeds go to extra life.

Answer (score 5):

You get to choose which armor calculation you wish to use according to both official WotC [Rules Answers](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-january-2016) and [Tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/803407127674925060) for reference from Jeremy Crawford.

Comment: keep in mind Tweets are not RAW, they are RAI.

Comment: In this case I don't think there is RAW/RAI distinction. I've added the January 2016 official WotC answer that expands upon the idea more and would be treated as RAW in nearly every instance I suspect.